# Run two Jetty servers in parallel

Tags: java, gradle, jetty

I have two projects:

```
A
--build.gradle

B
--build.gradle

settings.gradle // With: include 'A', 'B'
```

The setup is very minimal and each project is a simple Jetty server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String location = "src/main/webapp/";
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();

    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setResourceBase(location);

    server.setHandler(webapp);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

When I use `gradlew run` it only gets build to a certain percentage because after one project is build, the server is run in the foreground and the second project won't build.

Is there a good solution with Gradle or do I have to create fat JARs and do it manually via a post-compile task?

Comment: You may run it from another console.

Answer (score 0):

You are hard coding the port (8080). Two servers cannot start at the same port. If you can externalize the port to a config file and have two different ports to start., that should resolve your issue.,

If externalizing to config file seems difficult, make it an environment parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could do some hack along the lines of Tomás Lins ExecWait(http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/gradle-madness-execwait-a-task-that-waits-for-commandline-calls-to-be-ready/)

In short; Lin makes task called ExecWait that listens to a String output and then marks the task as completed.

Something that might work for you:
Slap on a String to wait for in your Jetty server

```
server.start();
System.out.println("We have liftoff");
server.join()
```

Create the ExecWait task in your own fashion

```
class ExecWait extends DefaultTask {
    String command
    String ready
    String directory

    @TaskAction
    def spawnProcess() {

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(' '))
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true)
        builder.directory(new File(directory))
        Process process = builder.start()

        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream()
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(stdout))

        def line
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            println line
            if (line.contains(ready)) {
                println "$command is ready"
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of ExecWait tasks along the lines of

```
task 'run-A-server'(dependsOn: 'jar', type: ExecWait) {
    doFirst {
        command "java " +                
                "-cp ${configurations.runtime.files.collect { it.absolutePath }.join(':')}:${jar.archivePath} " +
                "company.jetty.Main"
        ready "We have liftoff"
        directory "."
    }

}
```

A kill task is also convenient. This should work.

```
def freePort(int port) {
    def cmd = "lsof -Fp -i :$port"
    def process = cmd.execute()
    process.in.eachLine { line ->
        def killProcess = "kill -9 ${line.substring(1)}".execute()
        killProcess.waitFor()
    }
}
task 'kill-A-server'() <<{
  freePort(project.portServerA)
}
```

Add some mustRunAfter, dependsOn where you find it usefil and you should have something that might work to your liking.